# GDB: Print files that are recognised

Tags: c, gdb

How can I get GDB to print all the source files that it recognises? I've tried setting a breakpoint:

```
break test.c:35
```

but GDB complains:

```
No source file name test.c
```

However, I know that GDB *has* recognised this file because it recognises the functions defined in it.

Comment: So you can set breakpoints on functions, but not on file/line combinations?

Comment: @NiklasB.: Either that, or I'm not specifying the file correctly. Should I include the pathname, or should the file name suffice?

Comment: Try giving it the path relative to the current working directory.

Comment: @NiklasB.: I've tried that. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you running gdb in the same directory as `test.c`? If not, have you tried adding using `directory path/to/testdir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by `info sources` command.

```
(gdb) info sources 
Source files for which symbols have been read in:



Source files for which symbols will be read in on demand:

/root/test.cpp
(gdb)
```

In your case `test.c` should be listed.

Comment: Thanks. That prints out a bunch of files that *are* used, but not the ones I am looking for!